# UIImageView doesn't animate

Tags: iphone, animation, uitableview, uiimageview

I have the following code inside my app, but it doesn't animate the UIImageView, can anyone tell me why?

```
    UITableViewCell* cell = [selectedTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedPath];

    NSArray* myImageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"boxBeingChecked117x11" ofType:@"png"]],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"boxBeingChecked217x11" ofType:@"png"]],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"boxBeingChecked317x11" ofType:@"png"]],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"boxBeingChecked417x11" ofType:@"png"]],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"boxBeingChecked517x11" ofType:@"png"]],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"boxBeingChecked617x11" ofType:@"png"]],
                             nil];


    cell.imageView.animationImages = myImageArray;
    cell.imageView.animationDuration = 4.20;
    cell.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [cell.imageView startAnimating];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(methodToInvokeAfterAnimationIsDone)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
NSArray* myImageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxBeingChecked117x11.png"]],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxBeingChecked217x11.png"]],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxBeingChecked317x11.png"]],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxBeingChecked417x11.png"]],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxBeingChecked517x11.png"]],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxBeingChecked617x11.png"]],
                             nil];
```

You need to give name of the file, not the path, in `imageNamed`: method.

Comment: @user698952 - Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider changing your username so that other users will recognize you as a contributing community member. Also, remember to properly formulate sentences in your questions and answers. Spelling and grammar count! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `imageView`'s `highlighted` property is set to `NO`, otherwise the code you have above will not work. If you want to animate highlighted images, use `highlightedAnimationImages`.